# multi-threading, sampling and basic software issues

Tags: objective-c, c, core-audio

After disturbing you people so many times, i was talking with apple guys, and i have to get a decision which you probably know better than me .

I am dealing with audio in real time, read buffers ,DSP(FFT) and get a decision.
I have to send that decision to the main scene(or main thread), to do stuff in parallel. 
so, get audio buffers, and listen to decision in real time.

problem is: you cant put in audio callback function, objC functions, or other things that takes time,such as post a notification to other class when decision has made.

what i have tried yet :

1. put NSNotification in that callback to notify the main thread on the new data- it leaks.
2. put the decision in a global variable(singletone) then schedule that var from the main thread- which seems to be a bad idea ( and the NSTimer cant get under 50ms).
3. just call from the callback to another function in another class -to implement things in there- cause a leak- even if i just NSLOG something in there.
4. create another thread in another objC function,call it from the audio callback function, still, leaks (which means -the memory is growing fast! )

cant find the right way to do that .

for someone who want to take a look on the callback function (which called 1000's times a second )

callback :

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) 
{

    AudioBuffer buffer;
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2; //* sizeof(SInt16) ?
    buffer.mData = NULL;// malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 );

    // Put buffer in a AudioBufferList
    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;


    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit, 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             &bufferList); 


    SInt16 *targetBuffer = (SInt16*)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData;

// got the buffer, here i have tried so many things to do with it ,in order to not leak the app. i need to send it somewhere to process the data, or save it somewhere else.

   [globals sharedGlobals].bufBuf=targetBuffer;

    return noErr;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NSTimer in the UI run loop will fire about as often as the UI can be updated, so if the decision is to be displayed by the UI, just poll a flag variable in a repeating timer callback.  If another thread needs to update something more often, start that thread outside the audio callback, and just have that thread poll or wait on a lock.